# Is it possible to recreate a raid 1+0 array without losing data

Tags: raid

I have a HP smart array 6400 raid card and a 4 1TB raid 1+0 array, I was informed the power would fail for a shor time this afternoon. So I powered off the array and was surprised to find out that my raid array was lost when power restored. There are not any logical drives and all the 4 1TB disks are here so I can create a new array that includes them.

Before I do anything stupid, I would like to know that if I recreate a 1+0 array, will all my data disappear? Thank you for reading this

Comment: does your RAID card support re-scanning for recovery?

Comment: You have RAID 1+0 as in a mirrored pair of stripes? Then in the worst case you can test that by recreating one pair of the mirror.

Comment: there is a rescan option from the web management, but i only get individual disk ,not any logical drive

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume your data will be gone, always plan for the worst I find.

Odd that you'd lose the array though - were you using HP disks supported by that controller?

Comment: not consult HP disks supported yet , the card was bought at least 3 to five years from now, and i think the service period time may elaps.

Comment: yes it's odd , and i created another raid 0 array with two new 1tb disks for test,and power off ,power on , again and again, the raid array seems fine

Answer (score 1):

today , after had a full partition backedup, i recreted this 1+0 array, and the system immediately recognise the partition is linux, however , i couldnt mount the logical drive due to some errors , i have to perform a fsck, it took me a long time to finish checking disks, and a plenty of errors had been found, anyway , the resulti is that only about 43GB data were there , all other are gone

when i recreate the array ,there is a option to select stripe size, my predecessor couldnt remember what option he chose when he created this array , i have to leave it as default 128KB, i don't know if this is the cause

anyway, with backup in hand i can format and restore all the data

thank you for reading this

Comment: Could you answer my question (and ewwhite's linked one) about what type of disks you have, it's just that HP didn't make 1TB disks for that controller. That could be your problem.

Comment: the disks are all SATA

Answer (score 1):

Wait, this isn't possible. There were never any 1TB capacity SCSI disks available in the market. The [HP Smart Array 6400](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11587_na/11587_na.html) is a old-school parallel SCSI (Ultra-320) controller that only accommodated 68-pin or SCA hard disks. It did not support IDE drives.

What are you talking about here?

Edit:

So this is an [HP StorageWorks MSA20](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11942_div/11942_div.html) enclosure connected externally. This enclosure *does* support SATA disks.

Okay. Usually a full power-off and power on are needed. The BIOS prompts are very important in these situations, as HP Smart Array RAID configuration and metadata are contained on the disks, rather than the controller. Did you see any errors listing the number of logical drives or whether the array's disks were responding or not?

It's rare to lose data in this manner (assuming the disk drives were healthy), so I think you reformatted unnecessarily. If the drives are unhealthy, then you'll likely encounter problems in the future.

Comment: true, not SCSI disks, the card is connected with a disks container(i dont know how to call it)which equiped with 12 individual bays, i can install 12 disks in this container, and no SCSI disks , all of them ar SATA

Comment: Is this an [HP StorageWorks MSA20 enclosure](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11942_div/11942_div.html)?

Comment: yes, much like this

Comment: much like or exactly like?

Comment: yes, from the link i think it is this one

Comment: i did a few times of power-off and power on , and as i have said early, i created a raid0 with another 2 1tb disks when the problem took place, but the problem couldnt repeat itself. the POST was that it actuall told me there was 0 logical dirve, and when i entered the configuration, all disks are individual disk , no logical drive, and i didn't see any error messages during the post.

Comment: and i will prepare a few disks to replace any disk if the GREEN LED turn into AMber or something

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but back in the days of ProLiant 6400Rs, I remember having an array on a Smart Array 431 just dissappear.  Before going for a restore, I tried re-creating the array and the logical drives (EXACTLY the same size as before), and the data was intact.  Worth a try before you give up and resort to a restore...

Comment: well, if there is nothing better i can do, i will recreate this 1+0 array by the end of next week, and i will post the result to let you know ,thank you for sharing your experience